# Add new link to LinkCollection WatIn

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

I have div with 20 link but i need only link that have contains href=".do?" sow i dont know how to select Links to  linkCollection sow what i did is this take all 20 and cheking  1 by 1 if they contains Href and if (true) trying to insert to new LinkCollection ,BUT fail i cant add to new LinkCollecton

my code

```
 LinkCollection TempLinksOfAccounts = browser.Div(Find.ByClass("module")).Links;
    LinkCollection LinksOfAccounts;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TempLinksOfAccounts.Count; i++)
       {
        string Href = TempLinksOfAccounts[i].GetAttributeValue("href");

       if (Href.Contains("account-details.go?adx"))
            {
                               //Here i trying to do
LinksOfAccounts[index]=TempLinksOfAccounts[i];//fail
LinksOfAccounts.Add(TempLinksOfAccounts[i]);//fail
 LinksOfAccounts[index].Link=TempLinksOfAccounts[i];//fail
index++;

             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a link collection directly, you need to use its constructor, which will return the Link collection.

```
var finder = new NativeElementFinder(
() => browser.Body.NativeElement.AllDescendants,
browser.DomContainer,
new[] { ElementTag.Any },
Find.By("href", new System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex(@"*account-details.go?adx*")));

LinkCollection lc = new LinkCollection(browser.DomContainer, finder);
```

Now lc will have all the links, which contains href, as mentioned in the finder query. You can modify the finder query based on your need.

Comment: Hmmm... count=0 , i think it because Find.By("href", "account-details.go?adx") , my href NOT equals  account-details.go?adx,it have addition value that change evry time account-details.go?adx=1a2b3x, i need to use contains like i did i my code.How can i change Find.By("href", "account-details.go?adx")  to contains("href", "account-details.go?adx") ?

Comment: You can use Regex for sorting out that issue. I have updated my above post with Regex. Or you can use the below code as well.

   <br/> `LinkCollection lc = browser.Links.Filter(l => l.GetAttributeValue("href").Contains("account-details.go?adx"));`